# How to know where a child element located in a css grid container?

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid, webapi

Suppose we have html structured as such:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

#first style is uncertain, which means it may be styled like:
`grid-column: 1 span 2; grid-row: 1 span 2`

If so, #second will be located on the 3rd row, 1st column.

Do we have a generic method to know #second is located on which row and which column?

Comment: I don't think there is something like this. You could get the style of `#first` using `getComputedStyle`, but the style of `#second` is totally implicit and would have to be computed on your side based on the known style. The best way is likely to know every position of every element by setting it explictly.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking here. If looking just for CSS you can decide the order and layout with `grid-template-areas` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas

Comment: @RoniLaukkarinen I am writing a Vue component which is a grid container. And I leave the content totally to the component users. I hope the component can have maximum flexibility so that users can place elements however they want. Users will or will not apply `grid-template-areas` on the component. What I can do right now is using `window.getComputedStyle(parent).getPropertyValue('grid-template-columns')` and `window.getComputedStyle(parent).getPropertyValue('grid-template-rows')` to know the basic structrue of my grid. But I can not figure out which tracks one of the children is on.

Comment: @sjahan I also tried to access `window.getComputedStyle(second).getPropertyValue('grid-column')` and `window.getComputedStyle(second).getPropertyValue('grid-row')`. Both return `auto / auto`. Maybe, as you suggest, the only solution right now is to set explicit position on the children.